# Setting a custom content type for the azure event hubs message

Tags: rest, azure, azure-eventhub

In our streaming solution we're using event hubs which is great. We're using the content type to see what kind of message it is.

Now our external partner is putting messages on the hub via the rest api. But are running into problems because they can't set the content type of the message. No matter what we are trying we always get:

```
"contentType":{  
         "type":"application",
         "subtype":"json",
         "parameters":{  

         },
         "concrete":true,
         "wildcardType":false,
         "wildcardSubtype":false,
         "charset":null
      }
```

The REST call we're doing is working, the only thing we add in the headers is following:

```
Content-Type: vnd.mytype.v1+json
```

Is it possible to set a custom content type? When I read the documentation it seems possible:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/message-headers-and-properties#message-headers

Comment: can you provide the api link?

Comment: Do you mean this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/event-hubs-runtime-rest ?

Comment: can you use the EventData. properties option which can be set by the user and can be read while processing the message

Comment: @Aravind We're connecting via the REST api, and that does not seem to work. (if I understand correctly I can add custom headers as key value)

Comment: yes. In the link you shared above you can see how to set UserProperties in the header.

Comment: @Aravind I tried that by adding the header: "foo: bar" (just to test out) and it is completely ignored by the api. I also tried adding UserProperties as a header key and a JSON key value. Doesn't seem to do the job either.